# Proxmox HA Cluster tiebreaker node

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, proxmox

I want to setup a Proxmox HA Cluster using a quorum for reducing the risk for a split-brain. So I need 3 nodes.
Is it possible for one of the nodes to just act as a tiebreaker node without running any VM or container? That way I could use 2 rootservers and one simple vserver.

Comment: Two nodes running VM and one acting as a load balancer?

Comment: Two nodes running VMs and a 3rd running nearly nothing. Just so I have 3 servers for a proper quorum without the risk for a split brain in case the network fails.
The loadbalancer will also be redundant, but that's annother story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are actually two ways:

- A quorum disk (only works for older versions of Proxmox (<4), though): https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Two-Node_High_Availability_Cluster#Quorum_Disk_Configuration
- Just install 2 big nodes and a small node with no VMs/Containers on it.